# Book series about a dragon from his point of view, only male left in his litter

Tags: story-identification, books, dragons

There was a book I read my freshman year that I can't remember at all, but it starts with a dragon who was born as what is considered "weak" but turns out to be the strongest of his siblings, so he's the only boy with his sisters after he kills/drives off his other brothers. He has like leather skin and keeps his egg horn despite it itching like crazy, urging to be rubbed off like his other sisters have done. It's the first book of a series and it's killing me that I can't find it! Please help!!

Comment: When was your freshman year?

Answer (score 6):

This is [*Dragon Champion*](http://ageoffire.wikia.com/wiki/Dragon_Champion), by E.E. Knight, first book of the *Age of Fire* series:

> Deep in a cave underneath the Red Mountains, a small gray hatchling begins to break free of his egg, and witnesses his two male sibings - a Red hatchling and a Copper hatchling - instinctively fighting for control of the "shelf" their eggs have been laid on. Although the Red initially has the upper hand; crippling the Copper's foreleg and next attacking the gray, the two siblings manage to kill him after the gray guts him with his egg horn and the Copper crushes his throat. The gray then forces his Copper brother off the edge of the egg shelf and devours the corpse of the Red with the two remaining siblings - females - whereupon their mother names him Auron, and lulls him to sleep with a song - briefly waking later when his father arrives.

I found it with a search of *book series dragon "egg horn"*.

Comment: You can accept an answer by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons.

Comment: I've read some of these books.  At least the first two.  If this isn't the answer, I don't know what is.  Plus they are a really good story.